# Node.js (JavaScript) PDF creator (from templates)

Tags: javascript, pdf, node.js, pdf-generation

I need to generate PDF documents from some data and I also need some templating functionality. I have expirience with npm package `pdfkit`, but this package not support templates.

It would be nice if I will be able to make HTML or XML templates.

Any recommendations? (Not deprecated)?

Answer (score 1):

Use JS to write HTML Files, put these on a webserver that runs on localhost (or some webserver where you can upload files to). Call Google Chrome in headless mode to convert HTML to PDF:

```
URL=https://localhost:8000/myfile-created-from-js.html         # some HTML file
OUTFILE=myfile-created-from-js.pdf                             # PDF file
google-chrome --disable-gpu --headless $URL --print-to-pdf     # HTML 2 PDF
mv output.pdf  $OUTFILE                                        # rename PDF
```

I think that initially the  file will always be called `output.pdf`, so you have to rename it.

You can start a webserver on localhost with

`'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 > /tmp/simple-web-server.log 2>&1 &'`

Answer (score 0):

This project is a great match for what you want to do.

https://github.com/PDFTron/web-to-pdf

Blog describing the project: https://www.pdftron.com/blog/react/react-to-pdf/

Disclaimer this is from my company, but the web-to-pdf project is [GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE](https://github.com/PDFTron/web-to-pdf/blob/master/LICENSE) and allows commercial use.

Comment: It is using puppeteer, and I do not want to convert Recat components. But thanks :) I can use puppeteer alone then.

Comment: React was just used for the blog post. The github project has no mention/reference to React. Yes, you can use Puppeteer alone.

Answer (score 0):

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
What about this one? This is also javascript based, and provides templates.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing some highlights.